# Find the 5 most common words in a string

Tags: c#

Me and my colleague try to make a word counter that looks for the 5 most common words from a certain path and outputs them in the console. So far we have only managed to make a code that searches for the word we are entering and how many times it occurs.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace wordcounter_2._0
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie eine Keywort ein.");
            string patternWord = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie einen Pfad ein.");
            string Pfad = Console.ReadLine();
            try
            {
                StreamReader MyReader = new StreamReader(Pfad);
                string text = MyReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Bitte geben sie einen gültigen Pfad ein.");
            }
            string[] inputSentence = Console.ReadLine().Split();
            int count = 0;
            string pattern = @"(?:\b\w+\ \s|\S)*" + patternWord + @"(?:\b\w+\b\ \s|\S)?";
            Regex rx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            for (int i = 0; i < inputSentence.Length; i++)
            {
                var mc = rx.Matches(inputSentence[i]);
                foreach (Match m in mc)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Das Wort " + patternWord + " kommt " + "{0}", count + " mal vor.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Filburt If that is the case he will get only duplicate values of the same word. It will not him a most common unique words. I partially agree with you, but at the same time we need to perform distinct of those words using Distinct() :)

Comment: What you want to do, algorithmically, is to group all the same words together while keeping their count. Then order it by that count in a descending manner. And then take the top 5 of those words. So one way would be to have a `Dictionary<string, int>`, where the distinct words are the key and their count is the value. Then you can go through that dictionary and collect the five keys with the highest value. Which is a bit cumbersome. Luckily, with LINQ, this could boil down to something like `words.GroupBy(word => word).OrderByDescending(word => word.Count()).Select(grp => grp.Key).Take(5)`.

Comment: @Filburt - how is he supposed to put words in a list? OP doesn't know the words before hand, and thats where OP seems to be stuck he only knows how to search for a specific word but not how to parse the string get all words and count them. - and how should a `List<string>.Sort().Take(5)` result into the 5 most used words in the input string? Sort doesn't magically count the strings in the list, if there is a List<string> the only way I know of would be `List<string>.GroupBy(x => x).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).Take(5).Select(x => x.Key)`

Comment: @Corak - almost identical code :)

Comment: @RandRandom - similar to the (currently one) answer, too. LNIQ makes it so clear and obvious to express the intention.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string words = "I felt happy because I saw the others were happy and because I knew I should feel happy, but I wasn’t really happy.";
            string[] splitWords = words.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var commonWords = splitWords.ToList().GroupBy(e => e).Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() }).OrderByDescending(e => e.Count).Take(5);
            foreach (var x in commonWords)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Value: " + x.Value); // These are the 5 most used words, if you want you can include + " Count: " + x.Count to see count
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

This will solve your purpose

Comment: Ah, yes. Storing the result of `g,Count()`, so it doesn't need to be recalculated all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Here a regex based solution

```
string regWords = "I felt happy because I saw the others were happy and because I knew I should feel happy, but I wasn’t really happy.";
var regMatches = Regex.Matches(regWords, "\\b(?<word>[^\\s]+?)\\b");
var regCommonWords = regMatches.GroupBy(x => x.Groups["word"].Value).OrderByDescending(x => x.Count()).Take(5).Select(x => x.Key);
foreach (var x in regCommonWords)
        Console.WriteLine("Value: " + x);
```

To get an explanation what the regular expression does have a look at this:

https://regex101.com/r/OTBN5V/1

Tough keep in mind this solution is slower than the non-regex solution by splitting the string.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/E4GDrj

Used vinothvs answer to compare the speed differences.

**Warning:**

My solution doesn't treat "wasn’t" as a word but instead sees "wasn" and "t" as seperate words, couldn't find a satisfing way to solve this issue.